# Regular Expression for Telephone number with only 20 charcters allowed

Tags: regex

I want an regular expression in for international Phone Number which includes the follwing things : 
20 characters, 0-9 digit,"-" (Hyphen)," "(space),"(",")" (brackets)

I am using asp.net 4.0 and mvc 3.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are many variants. See examples here http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=telephone+number&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.. `^[0-9- ,]{20}$` I am not sure what you mean by brackets, but if you mean parentheses, then `^[0-9- ,\(\)]{20}$`

Comment: `Regex intphone = new Regex(@"^[0-9- ,\(\)]{20}$");

        Response.Write("345-345-345,345 345-          =          " + intphone.IsMatch("345-345-345,345 345-") + "<br/>");

        Response.Write("345-345-345,345345-           =          " + intphone.IsMatch("345-345-345,345345-") + "<br/>");

        Response.Write("abc-345-345,345345-           =          " + intphone.IsMatch("abc-345-345,345345- ") + "<br/>");`

Comment: 345-345-345,345 345- = True
345-345-345,345345- = False
abc-345-345,345345- = False

Comment: First one is a match (20 characters, numbers, hyphens, comma and space)
Second one is not (only 19 characters)
Last one is not (contains letters abc)

Comment: Maybe you mean, up to 20 characters, in that case, you can specify a minimum number like this `^[0-9- ,\(\)]{5,20}$`